# ¿Se puede obligar a un char a cambiar su codificación?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo entendido que para representar caracteres se utilizan la codificación y que dependiendo de cuál sea utilizada sobre un caracter, este puede pesar más o menos.

¿Es posible cambiar el tamaño u obligar a `System.Char` a representar los caracteres en 8 bits en .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con la documentación de Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx, esto no seria posible para el tipo de dato `System.Char` pues tiene un tamaño fijo ya establecido con el `Unicode de 16-bit`.

Ahora bien, si quieres trabajar con alguna Codificación especifica deberías utilizar tipos de dato `System.Byte` que junto con las utilidades de `System.Text.Encoding` te van a permitir trabajar con datos en otros formatos. Por ejemplo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Datos con los cuales se desea trabajar

```
char[] arrreglo = new char[] { 'H','o', 'l', 'a' } ;
```

Datos almacenados en un formato específico

```
byte[] bytesEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(arrreglo);
```

Datos decodificados desde un formato específico

```
string cadena = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesEncoding);
```

Comment: Lo que trato de hacer es algo de rendimiento respecto a la representacion de caracteres, dado que `char` usa 2 bytes, se complica en algunas operaciones que efectuaré, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puede aplicar un `encoding` a una cadena, la cual por supuesto es una representacion de un array de char

[Codificación de caracteres en .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx)

Podrias tener un array de char que sea de uno solo si es que necesitas trabajar con un unico char aplicando

[Encoding.GetBytes Method (Char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5881c0k9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

para obtener la representacion en byte de ese caracter, entonces seria

```
char[] chars = new char[] { 'z', 'a' };

Encoding u8 = Encoding.UTF8;

byte[] bytes = u8.GetBytes(chars);

for ( int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++ )
   Console.Write( "{0:X2} ", bytes[i] );
```

y para volver al string

```
string cadena = u8.GetString(bytes);

Console.Write(cadena);
```

Nota: recuerda definir el `using System.Text;`